# Unable to view child elements from OneDrive C# SDK

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am coding against the OneDrive C# SDK and I was shared a folder which contains multiple files. When accessing the shared folder from the `onedrive.com`, I am able to view the files -- however when trying to check the `Item` the children count is always at zero. I am assuming this may be some mix up on my end or permissions issue -- but I just wanted to run it past for a sanity check.

Code:

```
private async Task GetItem(string id = null)
{
    List<string> idsToSearch = new List<string>();
    var expandValue = this.clientType == ClientType.Consumer
            ? "thumbnails,children(expand=thumbnails)"
            : "thumbnails,children";
    try
    {
        Item folder;

        if (id == null)
        {
            folder = await this.oneDriveClient.Drive.Root.Request()
                           .Expand(expandValue).GetAsync(); //root
        }
        else
        {
            folder = await this.oneDriveClient.Drive.Items[id].Request()
                           .Expand(expandValue).GetAsync(); //children of root
        }

        WriteToFile(new List<string>(new[] { @"Folder: " + folder.Name }));

        if (folder.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            WriteToFile(new List<string>(new[] { @"NO Children" }));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var child in folder.Children)
            {
                WriteToFile(new List<string>(new[] { 
                @"Children of " + folder.Name + " : " + child.Name }));
            }

            foreach (var item in folder.Children)
            {
                GetItem(item.Id);
                idsToSearch.Add(item.Id);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        PresentServiceException(exception);
    }
}
```

I also included a snapshot of the `Item` object when it reaches the Shared folder object:

[image]

**Update**

After looking through the `folder` object some more I found that there is `RemoteItem` which is returning the correct number of child counts -- however does not have any meta data to fetch the child elements.

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot there's some `AdditionalData` - could you let us see what that is? It might provide some clues. Also, I assume the folder has valid data (e.g. name)? If that's the case you shouldn't have permission issues since permissions will always flow down the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @Brad - I had that idea too, however looking through it doesn't seem to offer anything that caught my eye. I did however update the photo.

Comment: Just standard OData stuff... nothing of use :). Does the `Folder.ChildCount` property contain the expected value?

Comment: @Brad the only thing that has the correct number lives in `folder.RemoteItem.Folder.ChildCount` returns 4. However, there is not data around the children.

Comment: Ahhhh, this is a remote item! That explains things - I'll answer

Comment: @Brad I added a picture to display the `RemoteItem` content -- as you can tell there is nothing other then `childCount`that has to do with the children items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on the question it was determined that this is a `RemoteItem` scenario. Remote items are different to local items - while there's some local metadata that's useful for rendering, the actual metadata for the item lives in another user's drive. Therefore, when such an item is encountered it may be necessary (e.g. if you need to enumerate children of a remote folder) for a subsequent request needs to be made directly for the item in question (using the `driveId` from the `remoteItem.parentReference` and the `id` from `remoteItem.Id`).

Have a look at [this documentation for some more information](https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/working-with-links.htm#enumerate-the-contents-of-a-shared-folder).

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense - so a separate call is required. Okay, now I have another question for you @Brad. Does this same approach work for if `user 1` shares a single loose file to `user 2` ? I am getting a similar issue - although I am unable to detect the file at all, I should also mention that this may because the file that is shared only lives in the *Shared* folder.

Comment: A file that's specifically shared (as opposed to one that's shared via a folder) cannot be "mounted" so they won't appear when you try to enumerate a drive. Instead you'll want to query https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/view.sharedWithMe

Comment: the link that you provided in your answer - seems to only be REST calls, is there an example of how to construct a `OneDrive C# SDK` way of passing in the `remoteItem.parentReference.DriveId`? 

Or would it simply be something like `await this.oneDriveClient.Drive.Items[id].Request().Expand(expandValue).GetAsync();` Where `id` would be the `driveId`?

Comment: Something like `await this.oneDriveClient.Drives[folder.RemoteItem.ParentReference.DriveId].Items[folder.RemoteItem.Id].Request().Expand(expandValue).GetAsync()` (disclaimer: untested :))